# Limit occurence from a value in a column with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, filter, count, pyspark

I would like to limit occurence from a value in pyspark.
I've tried :

```
table = table.filter(countDistinct(date_format(table['stamp'], 'yyyy-MM-dd')) == 4)
```

But it doesn't work because I have an error :

```
An error occurred while calling o110.showString.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot     evaluate expression: count(distinct date_format(cast(input[13, string, true] as timestamp) etc.
```

Do you have an other idea ?

Comment: It's not clear what your objective is with this code. Please see [how to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples) and try to include a small sample input and desired output. Aggregate functions need to be used in a `Window` or a `groupBy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be indeed good if you can come up with an example and the expected output. It is not clear why you use `countDistinct` if you want to check for occurrences of a value. Then you should rather use `count` in a `groupBy` statement.

This snippet might help you nevertheless:

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([
(1, datetime.datetime(2018,9,1,12)), (1, datetime.datetime(2018,9,1,12)),   (1,datetime.datetime(2018,9,1,12)), (1,datetime.datetime(2018,9,1,12)),
(1,datetime.datetime(2018,9,2,13)), (1,datetime.datetime(2018,9,2,13)),  (1,datetime.datetime(2018,9,2,13)),(2,datetime.datetime(2018,9,1,13)), (2,datetime.datetime(2018,9,1,13)), (2,datetime.datetime(2018,9,1,13))
], ("id", "time"))


occurences_df = df_new.groupBy("time").count().withColumnRenamed("time","count_time")
df_new.join(occurences_df, df_new["time"]==occurences_df["count_time"],how="left").show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
| id|               time|         count_time|count|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|  1|2018-09-01 12:00:00|2018-09-01 12:00:00|    4|
|  1|2018-09-01 12:00:00|2018-09-01 12:00:00|    4|
|  1|2018-09-01 12:00:00|2018-09-01 12:00:00|    4|
|  1|2018-09-01 12:00:00|2018-09-01 12:00:00|    4|
|  2|2018-09-01 13:00:00|2018-09-01 13:00:00|    3|
|  2|2018-09-01 13:00:00|2018-09-01 13:00:00|    3|
|  2|2018-09-01 13:00:00|2018-09-01 13:00:00|    3|
|  1|2018-09-02 13:00:00|2018-09-02 13:00:00|    3|
|  1|2018-09-02 13:00:00|2018-09-02 13:00:00|    3|
|  1|2018-09-02 13:00:00|2018-09-02 13:00:00|    3|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

Then you can filter by the count column for rows with the desired number of occurrences.